# Chrome extension - remove default text from forms using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, text, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing a Chrome extension, and I want to be able to insert saved data back into forms. In certain forms, some of the input elements will have default text. The problem I'm having is when I try to insert data into the form, the text retains the same class as if it was default text, and I want the text to appear as if a user entered it themselves. I tried triggering the 'focus' event for input elements with the following code:

```
valueInputs = ["input[type='text']", 'select', 'textarea'];
valueInputs.forEach(function(tag) {
    $('form').find(tag).each(function (index, elem) {
        if(tag != 'select') {
            $(this).focus()
        }
        $(this).val(data[$(this).attr('name')]);
    });
});
```

The code doesn't work for my extension, but does work when I type it in the console. Any suggestions on how to get it to run?

Update: I've figured out that after clicking a button in my popup to fill in the data, the data is filled in but nothing is focused on until I click the browser. Then it will trigger 'focus' only on the **last** input element. I want to be triggering the event for all input elements, and to fill in data **after** the element is focused on.

Comment: You'll have to show us more of the code.

Comment: Added the rest of the code

Comment: what do you mean by _the text retains the same class as if it was default text_ . Focus moves from tag to tag till last input

Comment: For example, when the page is first loaded all input boxes have the class '.defaultText', which causes the input text to be gray. Once you click the box and start typing, that class is removed and the text becomes black. When my program fills in the form, the text has the class '.defaultText' and is gray, hence it retains the same class as if it was default text. By triggering the 'focus' event, I hope to remove the defaultText class and make the text black.